# How to make Electron in a window on top of all other Windows as an indicator of Skype

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

Help to make the same window, as with Skype when we call, we see window with call info, via Electron. The point is that this window is always on top of all Windows on your computer, including games.

The `alwaysOnTop` parameter: true sets the window in front of all other Windows, but the game covers it in full-screen mode.

Is it possible and how it can be implemented in the Electron or in what ways it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, it is possible to set the window to be always on top with more options by using the BrowserWindow instance method `win.setAlwaysOnTop()` instead of the `alwaysOnTop` flag:

[win.setAlwaysOnTop(flag[, level][, relativeLevel])](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel)

> Values include `normal`, `floating`, `torn-off-menu`,
>   `modal-panel`, `main-menu`, `status`, `pop-up-menu`, `screen-saver`,
>   and `dock` (Deprecated). The default is `floating`.

You may want to try all possible level values to get the one which may fit your needs.

Comment: I need on windows

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667659/electron-create-a-window-above-all-the-others-even-fullscreen-and-hide-taskb) mentions the BrowserWindow `type` property with the value `toolbar` which is available in both Linux and Windows. You may give it a try...

Comment: Yes, I read this post, but this don't work in game. But Skype is good work https://i.imgur.com/aGX5yXn.jpg

Comment: anyone get this working? the toolbar type isnt in the official list type anymore, i tried all the alternatives but it wont work in he same way skype does

Comment: From electron 7 onwards "alwaysOnTop" has some changes. On windows to achieve any your electron window on top of any other window, even a fullscreen window do the following.
mainwindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'normal'); 
the default is "floating" which doesn't work as expected now.
Hope this helps!

Comment: @AlokKamboj thanks. This worked for me. I was stuck on something from past 2 weeks. I managed to make my windows always on top in electron 9.3.5 using a hack as mentioned in my answer but your suggestion worked for electron 13.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `window.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "normal")` does the trick as suggested by
[Alok Kamboj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5887385/alok-kamboj)

I was stuck on same thing and managed to make always on top work using this particular hack(in this particular order) -

```
// Tricky way to bring cam bubble to top over fullscreen windows on mac
  win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true, { visibleOnFullScreen: true });
  win.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "floating");
  win.setFullScreenable(false);
  // Below statement completes the flow
  win.moveTop();
```

Now this used to work when I was on electron 9.3.5 and stopped working after I upgraded to 13.1.2. Now I'm able to achieve the same thing using `"normal"`.